# Find rotate Quaternion from initial Quaternion

Tags: geometry, rotation, linear-algebra, quaternions

I'am totally beginner with Quaternion but I'am starting to use it. So I have a initial Quaternion for example `Q = (0.95, -0.17, -0,06, 0.23)` q0 from q3 left to right. I'd like to know how can I calculate the Quaternion who has rotate from 90° for example in x or z axis from my intial Quaternion Q, is it possible ? Should I multiply my `Q` by something ?

I found this code from Unity forum

```
 var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
 rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0); // this adds a 90 degrees Y rotation
```

What I understand from these lines, `rotation` is the intial Quaternion after thaht we multiply initial quaternion by another Quaternion coming from a transformation Euler to Quaternion is it right?

Edit : I found this Quaternion, he represents a rotation to 90° in x axis `Qr = (sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5), 0, 0)` so if I multiply my initial Quaternion `Q` by `Qr` will I get my initial QUaternion rotate by 90° in x ?

Comment: Yes, both approaches do what you describe. The first one "adds" a 90° rotation about the y-axis, the second one "adds" a 90° rotation about the x-axis.

Comment: Ok so I'am on the right way if I multiply my initial Quaternion Q by an another Quaternion, I will have the result of the rotation of Q by Qr,  thanks @Nico Schertler